# Vieta's formulas for multivariate polynomials

Tags: roots, multivariate-polynomial

Is there an equivalent of [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), relating the polynomial coefficients with its roots, for multivariate polynomials?

I tried to search for references but could not find anything.